# Navigate the menu items in onclick

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```html
<div id="menu" style="border-top:1px solid #ffffff;border-left:1px solid #ffffff;border-right:1px solid #808080;border-bottom:1px solid #808080">
<div style="padding: 4px 15px; background-color: rgb(212, 208, 200); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" onmouseover="hl(this,true);" onmouseout="hl(this,false);" onclick="select_menu('1','doc_107094');">Download...</div></div>
```

ONclick event Triggers options to download and edit the document

I am trying to navigate through the options from onclick event * edit and download

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='overDiv']/div/text()"))
```

Comment: Are these two tags siblings?

Comment: @Villa_7 second div is inside first div